# sort a range consisting of a single row

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

```
                     A              B             C
1                 zoo            aardvark      gorilla
2 =sort(A1:B1) ←  aardvark       gorilla       zoo
```

What I need to do is sorting the first row into the second one, ideally placing a formula involving `sort` in the `A2` cell.

Is there some (relatively) simple workaround that I can use to get what I want?

Answer (score 2):

To process a single row, try this in cell A2:

```
=split(textjoin("|",1,sort(flatten(A1:C1),1,1)),"|")
```

or

```
=transpose(sort(transpose(A1:C1),1,1))
```

For a more complex arrayformula, use:

```
=arrayformula(
{
indirect("A1:"&substitute(address(1,columns(A:C),4),"1",)&"1");
substitute(
vlookup(
sequence(max(if(A:C<>"",row(A:A)))-1,columns(A:C)),
{sequence(columns(A:C)*(max(if(A:C<>"",row(A:A)))-1)),query({array_constrain(int((row(A2:A)-2)/columns(A:C))+1,columns(A:C)*(max(if(A:C<>"",row(A:A)))-1),1),query({flatten(indirect("A2:"&substitute(address(1,columns(A:C),4),"1",)&(max(if(A:C<>"",row(A:A)))-1)+1)&char(9999))},"where Col1 is not null",0)},"order by Col1,Col2",0)}
,3,0)
,char(9999),)})
```

[image]

An adjust your range in place of `A:C`.

Comment: Oh! the first part almost satisfies the _"(relatively) simple"_ requirement, the second part… oh well!

Comment: I have checked the first part of your answer and it works OK, thank you and +1. I'll wait a couple days before accepting it…

Comment: You could also try: `=transpose(sort(transpose(A1:C1),1,1))`